# How to deny unencrypted uploads to an S3 bucket by any resource?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I want to prevent unencrypted uploads to an S3 bucket for all resources. I am attempting to do this using a S3 policy, as below:

```
PolicyS3BucketPolicy:
  Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
  DependsOn: PolicyS3Bucket
  Properties:
    Bucket: !Ref PolicyS3Bucket
    PolicyDocument:
      Version: "2012-10-17"
      Statement:
        - Effect: Deny
          Sid: DenyUnEncryptedObjectUploads
          Action: "s3:PutObject"
          Resource: "*"
          Principal:
            AWS: "*"
          Condition:
            StringNotEquals:
              "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "aws:kms"
```

The `PolicyS3Bucket` resource definition is omitted for conciseness.

When I attempt to deploy my service, I get this error:

```
PolicyS3BucketPolicy - Policy has invalid resource (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicy; Request ID: 5E5PR65Y1JY805Q0; S3 Extended Request ID: hxBAxt2qqqkgMRlF9JS5J0LFJ0EPxHU3mhIjYZ/x1kp+WT5FdlHSKEpY97x0gT2ZE0KXKMqzyKo=; Proxy: null).
```

How can I set the `Resource` value so that this policy denies for all resources?

Comment: Did you test with the actual bucket resource: `"arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"`? You can construct the ARN using some combination of !Ref and !Sub. Also, you should probably use `"Principal": "*"` rather than `AWS: "*"`.

Comment: It worked when I used `Resource: arn:aws:s3:::${self:custom.config.policyBucketName}/*`. @jarmod if you want to convert your comment into an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that problem is that your S3 bucket policy indicates:

```
Resource: "*"
```

It should be scoped to the actual bucket, for example:

```
Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
```

Or something like the following if you're using Serverless Framework:

```
Resource: arn:aws:s3:::${self:custom.config.myBucketName}/*
```